# Noise reduction before or after deconvolution?

Tags: post-processing, focus, astrophotography

NR before or after sharpening has been asked and answered, but deconvolution is much more complicated than simple USM.

Many deconvolution algorithms have their own methods of handling noise, so I'm wondering if using those features would handle noise better than pre-DC NR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AndyBlankertz - As I'm sure you are aware, when you are deconvolving some image, you'll deconvolve everything, including noise.  However, as I believed you were alluding, if those programs are able to base it's deconvolving on a threshold, then, some noise that is below the application's threshold might not receive any deconvolution treatment.

In situations like yours,I usually try a few tests when I'm developing a new workflow with new tools or new plug ins.  In your case with a new deconvolution tool, I might try deconvolution before and then try NR before and compare.

When it comes to NR, sometimes, I work in each color channel, because sometime noise may be more pronounced in one channel vs. another.

Or, in Photoshop,I might create a few layers of different treatments, then create a smart object, and then select the median values.

Comment: I've started tests, but when you think about the number combinations of image degradation and noise and NR programs... well, I was hoping to get lucky ;)

Comment: @AndyBlankertz - How is it progressing?  Were you able to find a reasonable solution?  Another item about noise reduction, when I can, I try to preclude it through 'image stacking'.  Of course, that advise doesn't help afterwards - but perhaps helpful as you are planning your next project.  There are a few registration and stacking tools made just for astrophotography - I've used DeepSkyStacker with some good results before - but that is just one of many out there.